# how to bind the model relation value in livewire wire:model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

There is a Product model with hasmany descriptions relationship.
descriptions relation has two columns, count, body.

How I must define the `wire:model` value to show the selected product descriptions values in Livewire Update component?

I must mention getting data from relation works fine just can't show data in the input tag of `wire:model` attribute! I think the problem is on the key definition of protected `$rules` or `wire:model` value!

the Update Class:

```
public $product;

protected $listeners = ['selectedProduct'];

public function selectedProduct($id){
    $this->product = Product::with('descriptions')->findOrFail($id);
}

protected $rules = [
    "description.count" => "required",
    "description.body" => "required",
];
```

the livewire view:

```
@if($product)
    @foreach($product->descriptions as $description)
        <input type="text" wire:model="description.count">
        <texatarea wire:model="description.body"></texatarea>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

the loop and number of filed is repeated correct but no data is shown!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things I'd like to mention, first is that your view should always only have *one* root HTML element - and subsequent elements that is generated in a loop should also have one unique root element inside, that has `wire:key` on it. The `wire:key` should be something unique on your page.

Then we need to have a look at the rules - its correct that any models needs a rule to be visible in input-elements, but you have a collection of elements, so the rules need to reflect that. To do that, you specify a wildcard as the key

```php
protected $rules = [
    "description.*.count" => "required",
    "description.*.body" => "required",
];
```

The fields then has to be bound towards an index, so Livewire knows its in a collection.

```php
<div>
    @if ($product)
        @foreach($product->descriptions as $index=>$description)
            <div wire:key="product-description-{{ $description->id }}">
                <input type="text" wire:model="descriptions.{{ $index }}.count">
                <texatarea wire:model="descriptions.{{ $index }}.body"></texatarea>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Finally, you need to declare the descriptions as a public property on the class, and store them there.

```php
public  $product;
public  $descriptions;

protected $listeners = ['selectedProduct'];
protected $rules = [
    "description.*.count" => "required",
    "description.*.body" => "required",
];

public function selectedProduct($id){
    $this->product = Product::with('descriptions')->findOrFail($id);
    $this->descriptions = $this->product->descriptions;
}
```